# How to determine if the time of day is between a certain range of hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have implemented a calendar type of application where some predefined time ranges exist in my database.

My Predefined Hours Table looks something like this:

> ```
> Id    int Unchecked
> StartTime varchar(50) Unchecked
> EndTime   varchar(50) Unchecked
> ```

And the values:

> Id    StartTime   EndTime
>
> 1 00:00   10:29
>
> 2 10:30   12:59
>
> 3 13:00   15:59
>
> 4 16:00   23:59

How can i determine using sql in which range does my current time falls into

Thanks in advance

Comment: what happens when current time falls out of these ranges like 10:29:25

Comment: @t-clausen.dk with the accepted answer i think it will be just fine because i will just provide hour:minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t char(5)='23:10'
SELECT *
FROM @yourtable
WHERE @t BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [date and time data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#DateandTimeDataTypes) instead of `varchar`, because SQL can understand the value of those types. `varchar` is just a string and SQL has no idea how to compare those. With a time data type, you can then use [BETWEEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) for your condition, something like:

```
(…) CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime (…)
```

Comment: I am afraid that my sql version doesnt support the Time datatype 'Type time is not a defined system type.' I use mssql 2008 R2...

Comment: sqlserver 2008 supports the datatype time. 2005 didn't maybe it is your compatibility mode.

Comment: My compatibility level is: SQL Server 2005 (90) ... how can i remove this?

Comment: this will not work, current timestamp will never be between starttime and endtime

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @t varchar(10)='00:10'
select id 
FROM tbl
where  convert(binary,@t) BETWEEN convert(binary,StartTime) 
       AND 
       convert(binary,EndTime)
```

Comment: data type binary is supported by sql server 2005

Comment: which benefit do you get from converting to binary ?